# Which solutions is the correct one?

Tags: java, swing

I started solving a question in Java but I made two solutions for it. Can you help me to find the right solution?

The question:

> Develop  an  interface  `GuestInterface` that includes a method `public boolean equals(Guest g)`. When this method is implemented, it compares the contents of two objects of the type `Guest` (see (b) below). The `equals` method returns true if the states of the two objects are identical, and false otherwise.

the first solution is :

```
Public interface GuestInterface
{


    public boolean equals(Guest g)
    {
    if((this.g == b)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
    {
{
```

and the other one is :

```
public interface GuestInterface {  
    public boolean equals (Guest g);
}
```

Which one of them is the right answer?

Comment: You made two solutions (where is the second?) and you don't even know which one works? Have you *tried* verifying if your code does what you want?

Comment: You might always want to check your grammar and structure of your post. It is not clear at all what you have tried here.

Comment: The first one doesn't even compile (for at least 6 different reasons!).

Comment: Well an interface is not supposed to have an implementation - for an interface the second solution is correct, but for an implementation, you will need to correct the code in the first `implementation` class - it only compares pointers (which is the default pointer comparison operator)

Comment: Also equals is a signature of Object interface. So its better to not to use it as overridden having different functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using methods of Object Interface. I would suggest to use different name like

```
public interface GuestInterface {  
    public boolean isSameGuest(Guest g);
}
```

Now you need to implement it on any class. Like if i create a Person class implements the interface.

```
public class Person implements GuestInterface{
    @Override
    public boolean isSameGuest(Guest g){
        //... your code goes here...
    }
}
```